# What is the encoded message?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, computer-puzzle

I created the puzzle by myself.

### ***Encoded Message***

[image]

---

### ***Examples***

***Hello***

[image]

***World***

[image]

***Hello, World!***

[image]

***Python***

[image]

---

Hints:

> Compass Rose

> Back in Time

> Rainbow

I made another image to illustrate the encoding better (all the images were generated by a Python program I wrote and I did not do any editing)

***Ξένη Γήινος***

[image]

---

Irrelevant information:

I just updated the function so that the bytes can be arranged in a circular fashion:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Looking at the "Hello" and "World" words, we see that:

> The lime circle is present only in lowercase letters. The same also happens in "Python". The yellow-green-cyan-blue pattern repeats twice in "Hello", representing the "l".

2. In "Hello, World", we see that:

> It is the concatenation of "Hello" and "World", with just three colored circles in the middle, which would be the comma and the space.

3. Further, we can note that:

> "o" in the end of "Hello" would have six colored circles.

4. It is reasonably to guess that:

> Each octet of circles encodes a letter and represents a byte. Hence, each circle is a bit.

5. Then:

> Comparing the "o" and the "n" from Python, the magenta circle is the least significant bit.

6. Throwing up the bit values and see where they the order is:

> Magenta (least significant), Purple, Blue, Cyan, Green, Lime, Yellow-orange, Red (most significant).

7. Thus:

> This perfectly matches the ASCII table.

8. Then, the message is:

> [Lindsey Stirling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindsey_Stirling)

Comment: But what is the message?

Comment: Yep, the encoding is ASCII, but you need to decode the message.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος DONE