# A rebus puzzle consisting of four characters

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, rebus, computer-puzzle

This is a rebus puzzle consisting of four characters. The puzzle is very simple if you're knowledgeable enough.

Given four characters, guess two words:

### ***ΔΕὖ%***

The first word consists of 5 basic Latin letters and the second word consists of 7 basic Latin letters.

So what is the answer?

---

### ***Hint***

> $$\frac{Δ} {5} \ \frac{Εὖ} {4} \frac{\%} {3}$$

---

### ***Final Hint***

> The previous hint describes how many letters each group of characters is mapped to, and you only need to figure out one word, because the first word is already given away by the first character.

Comment: The puzzle contains nothing fanciful, everything is actually quite straight forward. You only have to think outside of the box.

Comment: A little hint: this question is related to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116129/what-is-the-encoded-message), any more hints would practically be giving away the answer.

Comment: The answer is "no men", the aforementioned phrase has two intended hidden meanings, guess what they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the solution is

> Delta Goodrem

Explanation:

> Δ = Delta, Greek letter
>  Εὖ = Good in Greek (according to Google)
>  % = Rem, because "%" is the remainder operator in many programming languages (Thanks Lukas Rotter)
>  Google autocompleted my answer to give me the name of this singer I have never heard of.

Comment: rot13(% = zbqhyb bcrengvba = erznvaqre = erz)

Comment: @LukasRotter rot13(V gubhtug nobhg vg, ohg V'ir arire frra vg pnyyrq erz. Nyjnlf zbq)

Comment: You misspelt, that word is remainder, not reminder, I suggest you to edit your answer to correct it.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος done! sorry